# Bonding Fails in Kickstart %pre Section

Tags: centos, bonding, kickstart

I am trying to setup a bonded network from the %pre section of a CentOS 7 kickstart. I can prove the the following bonded network works:

```
network --device=mynetwork --bondslaves=eth0,eth1 --bootproto static --ip 192.168.0.1 --activate --onboot yes --noipv6 --netmask=255.255.0.0
network --hostname=testy
```

However, when I try to add that to `/tmp/network.ks` and importing, it doesn't work. I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

I add the import in the same place that the above lines were, like so:
`%include /tmp/network.ks`

Then I have the same lines appended directly to the import:

```
%pre
    echo "network --device=mynetwork --bondslaves=eth0,eth1 --bootproto static --ip 192.168.0.1 --activate --onboot yes --noipv6 --netmask=255.255.0.0" >/tmp/network.ks
    echo "network --hostname=testy" >>/tmp/network.ks
%end
```

Are those not functional equivalents since the documentation says:

> Use the %include /path/to/file command to include the contents of
>   another file in the Kickstart file as though the contents were at the
>   location of the %include command in the Kickstart file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I set up the bonded network from the `%pre` section, I need to set `--bondopts`. It is unclear why this works when it is not set in the main body as opposed to the `%pre` section, but I am posting this in case somebody has the same problem:

```
%pre
    echo "network --device=mynetwork --bondslaves=eth0,eth1 --bootproto static --ip 192.168.0.1 --activate --onboot yes --noipv6 --netmask=255.255.0.0 --bondopts=mode=active-backup,primary=eth0,miimon=80,updelay=6000" >/tmp/network.ks
    echo "network --hostname=testy" >>/tmp/network.ks
%end
```

That will achieve the desired result.